# How to use session id in where clause in laravel query builder?

Tags: laravel, session

> I have two tables.`users` and `company`. i am using auth for login and
>   registration. and i used user_id from `users` table as a foreign key
>   in `company` table. To store user_id from session i used hidden input
>   field.

```
@if (Auth::user())
   <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="userid" value="{{ @Auth::user()->id }}">
@endif
```

query for insert data in company table.

```
public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('username');
        $id = $request->input('userid');
        DB::table('company')->insert(
        ['com_name' => $name,'id' => $id]

        );
      return view('home');

    }
```

> Now, User will login himself and create multiple companies.Next time
>   when he will login he can see only list of his companies.

In current scenario i have this query but its not worth to used.

```
public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $companies = DB::table('company')->where('id', 1)->get();

        return view('dashboard', ['users' => $companies]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `id` to `user_id` here:

```
DB::table('company')->insert(['com_name' => $name, 'user_id' => $id]);
```

And here:

```
$companies = DB::table('company')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();
```

Alternatively, you could just do this:

```
$companies = auth()->user()->companies()->get();
```

Comment: $companies = DB::table('company')->where('user_id', 1)->get();
 it will display only user_id 1's data. and what if user_id 2 is logged in

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it's obvious and copy pasted 1 from you code. You should use `auth()->id()` instead of 1.

Comment: `$companies = DB::table('company')->where('id', auth()->id())->get();`
        
  i used this n i get all companies from table

Comment: Use my query instead of yours. It should be `user_id`, not `id`.

Comment: bro still i get all values from db. i used your code.

Comment: on insert query i got error of unknown column list `user_id` if i used `id` instead of then it stores data in db. my column name in `company` table is `id`

Comment: @amitsutar you've written you have `user_id` in your original question. If you don't have it, create it.

Comment: bro i already have `id` field in table. and i dont used `user_id`. i used `userid` as a input name only.